# Linear model in R - Multiplication Expression

Tags: r

I have 3 numerical variables `A`, `B` and `C`. I am trying to create a linear model capable of predicting `A`. The expression that I am using is the product of `B*C` in order to predict `A`; however, when looking at the output I am not able to get my equation because I get and extra variable that I don't know what is it.

Here is my code

```
MyData<-read.csv("...", header = T)
head(MyData,6)
str(MyData)

#Linear Model 
#Expersion A= B*C
Model1<-lm(MyData$A~MyData$B*MyData$C)
summary(Model1)
```

Output of `str(MyData)`

```
> str(MyData)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: num  2.5 3.4 2.7 3.6 2.5 2.1
 $ B: num  0.01 0.02 0.015 0.017 0.018 0.01
 $ C: num  0.1 0.2 0.27 0.19 0.17 0.16
```

Output of summary`(Model1)`

```
Call:
lm(formula = MyData$A ~ MyData$B * MyData$C)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.03945 -0.08386 -0.13925  0.67703 -0.40055 -0.01393 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          5.473      5.774   0.948    0.443
MyData$B          -222.431    454.508  -0.489    0.673
MyData$C           -26.482     36.222  -0.731    0.541
MyData$B:MyData$C 1938.961   2679.207   0.724    0.544

Residual standard error: 0.5688 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6149,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.03723 
F-statistic: 1.064 on 3 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.5178
```

`lm` uses the Wilkinson-Rogers notation so `"*"` is an iteration, based on the output, right? is this true, how do I create my model using the product of my two variables?

Comment: Is there a GIS component to your question?  To me it looks like it may more suited to researching/asking at [so].

Comment: Yes there is; however, I did not explicitly indicated/mentioned this in the post. All of these measurements have a lat long component. Unfortunately, I have not gotten to that part, because I am stuck on the model development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not a GIS question or spatial data...yet.

Comment: You should find a tutorial on linear models in R - there's enough out there that none of this should need repeating here until you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the product (or any in-formula calculation) use the `I()` function:

```
mod <- lm(A ~ B + C + I(B*C))
```

B and C should be included by themselves (as noted above). If they are not significant and the interaction term *is*, still leave them in.

Comment: Thank you at @Jackson. So from the output `summary(mod)` how do I interpret the results to get the actual equation in case B+C are not significant?

Comment: I would just state that on their own nieither B nor C have a significant impact, however their interaction does. But you still need to leave them in the formula in the event that `I(B*C)` is significant!